# Change values above 1 to 1 in a vector3

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a vector3 with these values:

```
Vector3 bla = new Vector3(1.0f,8.0f,16.0f);
```

I want every value that is higher then 1 to be 1, is there an easy way to do that?  I could write a function to do it, like:

```
void ValueToOne(Vector3 _input)
{
   float x = _input.x / _input.x;
   float y = _input.y / _input.y;
   float z = _input.z / _input.z;

   return new Vector3(x,y,z);
}
```

But I thought maybe Unity has something to do that already?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [Vector3.Min](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Min.html) function to do this:

```
Vector3 clampedVector = Vector3.Min(Vector3.one, yourVector)
```